# infinite loop even when I switch off capslock

Tags: c#

I am trying break; out of frustration. Is there an event handler I need to know about in console?

[image: Infinite loop]

Comment: See http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/105103-how-detect-capslock-csharp.html

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of your code.  Paste the actual text.

Comment: Do you have a plush bear or a rubber duck? If not, you must get one. Then, please use it well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only setting the value of `capslock` once, prior to entering the loop.  `bool` is a value type, so you get a copy of the `Console.CapsLock` property, not a reference to it. Your variable is never going to change value after that first assignment.  What you want is something like:

```
while(Console.CapsLock)
{
    // inform user, perhaps remove the loop and just tell them once
}
```

Or

```
capslock = Console.CapsLock;
while(capslock)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CapsLock on");
    capslock = Console.CapsLock;
}
```

On a side note, writing a message as fast as possible in a loop is probably a bad idea since it's just going to fill up the screen before the user has a chance to do anythign about it.

Comment: yes I will use the thread.sleep and console.clear(), dont worry

Comment: @MarietjieDavel: If you're using `Thread.Sleep` you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not to answer your original question but it appears the reason you are checking for caps lock is you want the username that is going to be typed in in all lowercase so you can do a `users.Contains(username)` or something similar below where you provided in the screenshot.

A better way to do it is use the contains overload that lets you set a comparer, then use a case insensitive string comparer to test.

```
if(users.contains(username, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //username existed
}
else
{
   //username did not exist
}
```

There are similar overloads for [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) that lets you ignore case too

```
//This would return true if "username = marietjie" and "testUsername = MARIETJIE"
if(username.Equals(testUsername, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //username matched
}
else
{
   //username did not match
}
```

Answer (score -4):

The solution for this kind of problem!!

[image: This worked!!!]

Comment: Please stop posting pictures of your code. There is a button to make code look correct on the website `{ }` copy and paste your code here, highlight it, and press that icon.